# HttpContext.Current.Application is there a limit/bottleneck on how many keys can be stored in IIS?

Tags: .net, iis

I'm using Couchbase as key/value storage and recently I have started to decorate the most frequently used cache keys with HttpContext.Current.Application.

I'm doing this by returning value from httpContext first if exists, else get from couchbase, then save to httpContext, and then returning back the value. This makes sure that the next calls will always get value from httpContext, and if for some reason IIS recycles it will always fall back to getting the value from couchbase and the key value will be readded back to the context.

This approach have had a huge postive impact on the performance of my application, and I'm concidering to scale this strategy up by adding a lot more cache keys into this decoration.

However I'm afraid there could be some bottlenecks if we start to store a lot of key/values in the HttpContext.Current.Application storage. Does anyone have experience on this? Do I have anything to worry about?

Say I start stuffing in a lot of data to the HttpContext.Current.Application. In the size of 10k+ keys and more.

Could requests start to become slow just because this storage contains lots of data?

Or could it start flushing itself endlessly because i just keep stuffing in to much data to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.Application is essentially a hangover that is needed for backwards compatibility with classic asp. It is simply a reference to static global HttpApplicationState object in .net for web application, of which there should be one global instance per web application. By storing data there, you can provide fast, thread-safe access to your global variables.

You are very smart considering that it will reset with the iis reset. Then what needs to be considered is the number and structure of servers. If you are deploying to a single web server the approach would work. However, if you are going to deploy to a web server farm, application only typically exist in a single server context.

Comment: yeah, we are deploying to a webfarm so I am aware that I can't use this approach on key/values that needs to always be up to date between each web server.

But my concern with this approach is if i start stuffing in 10k+ keys to the HttpContext.Current.Application is that something goes terribly wrong. Could requests starts to become slow just because this storage contains lots of data?

Or could it start flushing itself endlessly because i just keep stuffing in to much data to it?

Comment: Usually, application does not store too much data, nor does it frequently refresh the data. It is more important to store key data that is more frequently used. This type of data runs through the entire request and the call will cost performance. Application is actually a static global object. It must be locked, modified and then unlocked every time the data is updated. If the modification is too frequent, it may indeed cause slowness

Comment: Many data can cause the slow performance of the site. If possible use less key and value or you could store the key and value in the database and then use it. You should look at the System.Web.Caching namespace for more advanced scenarios. Also, if you are in a web farm or cluster of some sort, you may need to roll your own global data store so you can share it across multiple servers.